# Blazor PWA magic makes basic functionality disappear

Tags: blazor

Im using Blazor and the NuGet-package "BlazorPWA.MSBuild" which automagically makes a PWA out of your Blazor Web App. This "works", but in the process the menu and any other button clicks ha stopped working.

This is tested from a brand new Blazor project in VS

Im going to test to create these files myself, but in the meantime, is there any trick to get this working.

Comment: Is the project available? I could take a look...

Comment: Check this link https://dev.to/bradwellsb/a-simple-way-to-create-a-pwa-with-blazor-webassembly-1fln